# Camera onActivityResult on fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, camera, fragment

I'm working on some code someone else wrote and I'm having trouble handling the result of a camera intent.

Basically i have a DashBoardActivity which contains a tab with a fragment called "MyProfileContainer", which contains a "SettingsFragment" fragment which contains a "EditProfileFragment"fragment.

In the EditProfileFragment the user can take a picture for his profile. It works but it calls the onActionResult on the Dashboard Activity.

I read some guide on how to redirect it to the EditProfileFragment but I haven't been able to do it.
I'm losing literally days on this one and I can't figure it out.

This is onActivityResult on the Dashboard Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And this is EditProfileFragment

```
private  Uri imageUri = null;

public void captureImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                    profilePhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedImage.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }

}
```

I don't know if I have to override the method on every class between this two or if I'm doing something else wrong, but I'm sure the EditProfileFragment onActivityResult is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, and it was actually a bug of Android.

The fragment that was to recieve the result was a fragment nested inside other fragment and the method call was not properly propagated that deeply.

I had to override the method on the containing fragment manually and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The easy trick to call OnActivityResult in nested fragment.

1) Add this code in your captureImage method it will start a new activity.

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CameraPreviewActivity.class);

startActivityForResult(intent, 111);

2) Now CameraPreviewActivity activity will open and it will start camera activity and returns the result to fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FragmentAccPhoto.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```